# access2010 form with a non selectable combo box

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access 2010 form with a combo box. When I run the Ado query the drop down list shows but when I try and select nothing is selected and the message at the bottom of the screen says form 'readonly'.

Comment: Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
With rs
Set .ActiveConnection = cn
.Source = "select distinct assignedto from pc3claims where assignedto is not null order by AssignedTo"
.LockType = adLockOptimistic
.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
'must use aduseclient to have a bindable recordset.
.CursorLocation = adUseClient
.Open
End With
Set Me.Recordset = rs
'Me.RecordSource = rs.Source
Set cboAssociate.Recordset = Me.Recordset
cboAssociate.ControlSource = AssignedTo
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using the same recordset for the form and the combo box.

You can use just the sql statement to populate your combo box using the Row Source property and set the Bound Column to 1.

```
cboAssociate.RowSource =  "Select distinct assignedto from pc3claims where assignedto is not null order by AssignedTo" 
cboAssociate.BoundColumn = 1
```

This will populate your combo with the AssignedTo values and you can then set the Control Source to the AssignedTo field in your form's recordset.